Binary not converting to image in browser(SPACES Digital Occean)
I recently moved to S3 to DigitalOccean Spaces and everything seems to work perfectly, but i noticed my images are not working correctly, every other type of archive is working just fine. My image binary is not being shown in the browser. Does anyone have a hint(every other kind of file works just fine)?
This is my php code
        require_login();

        $db = new db();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE id = {$id}";
        if (!super()) $sql .= " AND empresa = " . session('empresa');
        $file = $db->row($sql);

        if (!$file || !session('empresa')) {
            return json_encode(
                [
                    'error' => true,
                    'message' => 'File not found or you do not have access to it.'
                ]
            );
        }

        $content =  Storage::read(
            $file->empresa . '/' . $file->modulo . '/' . $file->nome_atual
        );

        header("Content-Type: {$file->ext}");
        header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $file->nome . '"');
        header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

        echo $content;
    } 


That is typically the sign of a bad Content-Type. If you look at the metadata of an object that is already stored, what is its Content-Type? It should be something like image/jpeg but your code looks like it is using $file->ext.

#1 from aws-s3 to digital or from digital to aws-s3  #2 If you file is stored as binary directly into the sql database, file storage like aws s3 is not related #3 Did you try the #
John-Rotenstein comment? #4 Share us your sql table definition and the error in the web developer (browser inspect) related to the image
